# Calculate Quantity Based on First in, First Out (FIFO)

Tags: mysql, running-totals

I'm trying to get result of quantity based on FIFO, with 2 tables below:

Table Purchase:

```
| PO    | Date         | Quantity | Item | 
|-------|--------------|----------|------|
| PO001 | 01-Jan-2016  | 3        | AO21 |  
| PO002 | 10-Jan-2016  | 7        | AO21 |  
| PO003 | 01-Feb-2016  | 3        | AO21 |
```

Table Stock:

```
| SO    | Date        | Quantity | Item |
|-------|-------------|----------|------|
| SO001 | 02-Jan-2016 | 2        | AO21 |
| SO002 | 11-Feb-2016 | 8        | AO21 |
| SO003 | 12-Feb-2016 | 6        | AO23 |
```

I want output to be like this :

```
| SO    | PO    | Quantity |
|-------|-------|----------|
| SO001 | PO001 | 2        |
| SO002 | PO001 | 1        |
| SO002 | PO003 | 7        |
```

Do you have any idea of query for view this output? Result from calculated SO and PO in row. some more explanation:

> Where do the 2, 1, 7 come from in the wanted result?

From `stock` and `purchase`. The first (by date) stock value for item `A021` has 2 and the first purchase (`PO001`) needs 3, so stock sold 2 and we get this row in the result:

```
| SO001 | PO001 | 2        |
```

We still need 1 more for the purchase and then next stock value is 8. So this purchase is completed and we get 1 (and 7 left in stock):

```
| SO002 | PO001 | 1        |
```

The next purchase (`PO002`) needs 7 and we have exactly 7 left, so the purchase is completed (and 0 stock left for that item). We get:

```
| SO002 | PO003 | 7        |
```

Purchase `PO003` needs 3 but there is no stock left, so we get no rows in the result for that purchase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a trivial problem but it wouldn't be very hard with window functions (and CTEs for readability).

MySQL has not implemented either but lets see how it could be done:

```
WITH 
  running_purchase AS
  ( SELECT po, date, quantity, item,
           SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY item
                               ORDER BY date, po
                               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                        AND CURRENT ROW)
             AS running_total
    FROM purchase
  ),
  running_stock AS
  ( SELECT so, date, quantity, item,
           SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY item
                               ORDER BY date, so
                               ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                        AND CURRENT ROW)
             AS running_total
    FROM stock
  )
SELECT 
    s.so, p.po, p.item,
    LEAST(p.running_total, s.running_total) 
    - GREATEST(s.running_total - s.quantity, p.running_total - p.quantity)
        AS quantity
FROM running_purchase AS p
  JOIN running_stock AS s
    ON  p.item = s.item
    AND s.running_total - s.quantity < p.running_total  
    AND p.running_total - p.quantity < s.running_total 
ORDER BY
    p.item, p.date, p.po ;
```

Tested at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3c32c/3) (in Postgres).

Note that MariaDB (which can replace MySQL) has announced that they are working on window functions and CTEs, probably on their next version (10.2). See [MariaDB 10.2 Release notes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-1020-release-notes/).

---

For current MySQL versions, it has to be more complex but the logic is the same:

```
SELECT 
    s.so, p.po, p.item,
    LEAST(p.running_total, s.running_total) 
    - GREATEST(s.running_total - s.quantity, p.running_total - p.quantity)
        AS quantity
FROM 
     ( SELECT p1.po, p1.date, p1.quantity, p1.item,
             SUM(p2.quantity) AS running_total
       FROM purchase AS p1
         JOIN purchase AS p2
           ON  p1.item = p2.item
           AND  ( p1.date > p2.date
               OR p1.date = p2.date AND p1.po >= p2.po)
       GROUP BY p1.item, p1.date, p1.po
     ) AS p
  JOIN
     ( SELECT s1.so, s1.date, s1.quantity, s1.item,
             SUM(s2.quantity) AS running_total
       FROM stock AS s1
         JOIN stock AS s2
           ON  s1.item = s2.item
           AND  ( s1.date > s2.date
               OR s1.date = s2.date AND s1.so >= s2.so)
       GROUP BY s1.item, s1.date, s1.so
     ) AS s
  ON  p.item = s.item
  AND s.running_total - s.quantity < p.running_total  
  AND p.running_total - p.quantity < s.running_total 
ORDER BY 
    p.item, p.date, p.po ;
```

Tested at [SQLFiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d4db4/1) (in MySQL 5.6).